# change date format to numbers in php

Tags: php, format

Please, how i can change date format in php

from something like 2012-12-14 08:40:26

to format number like 28124629523

Comment: Any search on Google or Stack Overflow can find this answer.  Lucky John only took 9 seconds to answer this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FYI, what you're looking for is called a [Unix Timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)

Use [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
echo strtotime('2012-12-14 08:40:26');
```

or [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2012-12-14 08:40:26');
echo $datetime->getTimestamp();
```